# Magento 1.2 - Changes are required to your PayPal integration

Tags: magento, paypal, e-commerce

I received an email from PayPal informing me to do the necessary changes for the PayPal integration before the stated deadline. Otherwise the integration will not work. My Magento version is 1.2.0 and I am not sure what are the changes I need to do. The screenshot of email is below. Could some one advise me on this?

[image]

Comment: Most of this is server maintenance. You should be running on a late version Linux distribution that is getting current curl and OpenSSL updates. Magento 1.2 is so dead and gone that any fixes may require module backporting from a later version (IPN stuff).

Comment: Hi Fiasco, Thanks. I am going to revamp the website soon. Does the magento use GET Method for  classic NVP/SOAP APIs? Will it affect my website?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?